# How do I use unicode characters in FitNesse fixtures?

Tags: java, fitnesse

I'm testing the workings of a unicode-scrubbing routine using FitNesse, but the unicode characters I enter in the decision table don't make it through to my fixture.

The decision table looks a little like this,

```
|first name before|last name before |first name after|last name after  |
|Władysław        |Belina-Prażmowski|Wladyslaw       |Belina-Prazmowski|
```

but setters in my fixture get called with

```
W?adys?aw
```

and

```
Belina-Pra?mowski
```

where I would have expected multibyte characters (yes, that actually is a '?' character).

How can I instruct FitNesse to pass these characters on as unicode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it works without any particular problem. Check to have unicode as system charset and in java enviroment.

Comment: Turns our you're right. I'm on a Mac, which uses MacRoman encoding by default. To make Slim use UTF8, use !define COMMAND_PATTERN {java -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -cp fitnesse.jar:%p %m }